# Finding solutions for system of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

How does one find solutions for the system of differential equations of the form

$$2x'-5y'=4y-x \\ 3x'-4y'=2x-y$$
?
All I can think of, is finding $x'+y' = 3x-5y$ and then substituting $x'$ or $y'$ in one of the equations, but the result is not satisfactory (for instance I get $y'+2y-x=0$). This system is just one example, I found whole exercise with equations like these and I'm trying to learn how to tackle such problems. I know the other approach is to create and work with a matrix, but to do that the system should be somehow transformed to the form $x'=f(x,y)$ and $y'=g(x,y)$ and I don't see a way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $D$ stands for `'`. I mean $y'=Dy$ so the system can be written as follows. Note that after doing this job we treat the system as a linear system and you know that what I did in the third and the fourth systems:

[image]

Lets work on the last equation in which I omited the part $x(t)$'s. We get $$(ad-bc)y(t)=...=(D^2-1)y(t)=0\Longrightarrow y(t)=C_1e^{t}+C_2e^{-t}$$ wherein $C_1,~C_2$ are constants. Now work on $x(t)$ by omitting the $y(t)$'s parts from the third system.

Answer (score 1):

The system can be written as 
\begin{equation*}
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & -5 \\
3 & -4
\end{array} \right) \cdot \left(
\begin{array}{c}
x' \\
y'
\end{array} \right) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 4 \\
2 & -1
\end{array} \right) \cdot \left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y
\end{array} \right) 
\end{equation*}
and therefore 
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x' \\
y'
\end{array} \right) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & -5 \\
3 & -4
\end{array} \right)^{-1} \cdot \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 4 \\
2 & -1
\end{array} \right) \cdot \left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y
\end{array} \right) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & -3 \\
1 & -2
\end{array} \right) \cdot \left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y
\end{array} \right) 
\end{equation} 
and the solution of the system is

\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y
\end{array} \right) = \exp( (t-t_0)\cdot \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & -3 \\
1 & -2
\end{array} \right) )\cdot \left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_0 \\
y_0
\end{array} \right)= \ldots
\end{equation}